# Show every author in bibliography with natbib

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, author

I am writing my thesis. I use this code for my bibliography:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside=off,
bibtotoc,liststotoc,appendixprefix,paper=a4,headings=small]{scrbook}
    
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{./Literatur/quellen}
\end{document}
```

And for my source I have this:

```
@book{FendrichHandbuchEI,
publisher = {Springer Vieweg},
isbn = {9783662560617},
year = {2019},
title = {{Handbuch Eisenbahninfrastruktur}},
edition = {3},
copyright = {Springer-Verlag GmbH Deutschland, ein Teil von Springer Nature 2019},
language = {ger; eng},
address = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
author = {Rießberger, Klaus and Fendrich, Lothar and Gerber, Ulf and Fengler, Wolfgang and Linsel, Ralf and Meißner, Klaus and Rahn, Horst and Lay, Ekkehard and Jänsch, Eberhard and Mölter, Tristan},
}
```

In my document it looks like this:

[image]

How do I show all the authors and not the dots in between?

Every help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The `apacite` bibliography style implements the APA6 formatting guidelines for bibliographies. These guidelines feature a special truncation mechanism for publications with more than eight authors. If you don't like this style, you probably shouldn't be using the `apacite` bibliography style.

Comment: Incidentally, loading the `apacite` and `natbib` citation management packages independently is a mistake (and you should be getting lots of complaints from LaTeX about this...). You've got to use the `apacite` package in order to employ the `apacite` bibliography style. If you want to employ natbib-like commands such as `\citet` and `\citep` alongside the `apacite` package, you need to execute `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}`.